# How do I "say" to the Telegram API that I got their webhook request successfully?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm adapting my Telegram bot to accept webhooks requests instead of doing constant polling, so I read the [Telegram API documentation about the setWebhook method](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook).

I'm using Python's micro-framework Flask to create my web application that receives the request.

Somewhere in the documentation it says "In case of an unsuccessful request, we will give up after a reasonable amount of attempts.". What does it mean? Do I have to return something specific in my @app.route decorator so the API understand I got what I wanted? I don't have much knowledge on web application so I have no idea how to say "hey I got what you sent".

Comment: That means: if the server receiving the hebhook call fails they will not retry forever.

Comment: Oh yeah maybe I didn't elaborate in the right way. What I actually mean is "how do I say to the API I received the request and processed it succesfully?". Sorry about that, I'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: Return a valid status code indicating success, like `200`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means if it fails to send the update (for example if your webhook is down). You don't have to return anything, you just need your webhook to be active by the time.

Comment: So just by receiving the request it'll be seem as "successfull" right?

Answer (score 1):

The Webhook approach allows Telegram to push the messages to your backend.
The Webhook should normally always be online, but if it is down the message (on Telegram side) is queued for a while.

This works nicely when your Flask app needs some time, for example, to startup.

Note the message is delivered once: if the Webhook fails (backend error) and return an error text or http status code (403) the  message is consumed and will not be re-sent.

Comment: Not that I've deeply researched this matter, but my quick experiments show that returning error code causes Telegram to retry the request (I did not try 403, but it's true for 400 and 500). So beware that there is no way to respond to Telegram with something like "I don't understand anything, please do not send this again". Moreover, Telegram won't send you next updates (at least from this chat) unless you properly (with 2xx status code) deal with current one. This is consistent with tg docs saying "In case of an unsuccessful request, we will give up after a reasonable amount of attempts"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Telegram Bot Api is expecting only http status codes between 200 and 299 for a successful request.

```
if (200 <= response->code_ && response->code_ <= 299)
```

https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api/blob/5d88023dd1e65b7d0926a71aea4487d6cac3bf13/telegram-bot-api/WebhookActor.cpp#L619